# How do I parse an array inside parsed JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm using an API that returns JSON that looks like this

```
{
   "boards":[
      {
         "attribute":"value1"
      },
      {
         "attribute":"value2"
      },
      {
         "attribute":"value3",
      },
      {
         "attribute":"value4",
      },
      {
         "attribute":"value5",
      },
      {
         "attribute":"value6",
      }
   ]
}
```

In Swift I use two functions to get and then parse the JSON

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest))
}

func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
    var error: NSError?
    var boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    return boardsDictionary
}
```

and then I call it using

```
var parsedJSON = parseJSON(getJSON("link-to-API"))
```

The JSON is parsed fine. When I print out

```
println(parsedJSON["boards"])
```

I get all the contents of the array. However I am unable to access each individual index. I'm positive it IS an Array, because ween I do

```
parsedJSON["boards"].count
```

the correct length is returned. However if I attempt to access the individual indices by using

```
parsedJSON["boards"][0]
```

XCode turns off syntax highlighting and gives me this:

[image: XCode Error]

and the code won't compile.

Is this a bug with XCode 6, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: parsedJSON["boards"][0] is surely objective-c literal but is it also swift syntax? not sure about that (but i guess it is)

Comment: It seems like there are several bugs related to arrays of dictionaries at this point.  I'm currently beating my head against it as well.

Comment: Your parseJson function will crash if there is an error parsing and nil is returned. The "as NSDictionary" is the culprit. See my answer here for correct syntax on how to parse JSON with NSJSONSerialization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24333999/1687195

Comment: Xcode crashes at strange times, it probably not your code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dictionary access in Swift returns an Optional, so you need to force the value (or use the `if let` syntax) to use it.

This works:
`parsedJSON["boards"]![0]`

(It probably shouldn't crash Xcode, though)

Comment: I'm rather looking for something like:

myDto: MyDTO = getJson()

println(myDto.field)

println(myDto.anotherField)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look here:https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON

```
let json = JSONValue(dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string{
    //Now you got your value
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a variable

```
var myBoard: NSArray = parsedJSON["boards"] as! NSArray
```

and then you can access whatever you have in "boards" like-

```
println(myBoard[0])
```

Comment: anytime you cast the parsed data to array you get an error.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to deal with this would be to check the return from the dictionary key:

```
    if let element = parsedJSON["boards"] {
        println(element[0])
    }
```