# swift programming NSErrorPointer error etc

Tags: swift, xcode6, nserror

```
var data: NSDictionary = 
    NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: error) as NSDictionary;
```

This line of code gives me error

```
NSError is not convertable to NSErrorPointer.
```

So I then thought to change the code to:

```
var data: NSDictionary =
     NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as NSDictionary;
```

which would turn the NSError error into a NSErrorPointer. But then I get a new error and cannot make sense of it:

```
NSError! is not a subtype of '@|value ST4'
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

These types and methods have changed a lot since Swift 1.

1. The `NS` prefix is dropped
2. The methods now throw exceptions instead of taking an error pointer
3. Use of NSDictionary is discouraged. Instead use a Swift dictionary

This results in the following code:

```
do {
    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
        with: responseData,
        options: .allowFragments)
    if let dictionary = object as? [String:Any] {
        // do something with the dictionary
    }
    else {
        print("Response data is not a dictionary")
    }
}
catch {
    print("Error parsing response data: \(error)")
}
```

Of, if you don't care about the specific parsing error:

```
let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
    with: responseData,
    options: .allowFragments)
if let dictionary = object as? [String:Any] {
    // do something with the dictionary
}
else {
    print("Response data is not a dictionary")
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

Your NSError has to be defined as an `Optional` because it can be nil:

```
var error: NSError?
```

You also want to account for there being an error in the parsing which will return `nil` or the parsing returning an array. To do that, we can use an optional casting with the `as?` operator.

That leaves us with the complete code:

```
var possibleData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
    responseData,
    options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,
    error: &error
    ) as? NSDictionary;

if let actualError = error {
    println("An Error Occurred: \(actualError)")
}
else if let data = possibleData {
   // do something with the returned data
}
```

Comment: This will crash if there is an error parsing the json and nil is returned. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24333999/1687195

Comment: I updated the answer to prevent crashes from a parsing errors

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned, the error must be defined as optional (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

However - This code WILL CRASH if there is an error and nil is returned, the "As NSDictionary" would be the culprit:

```
var data: NSDictionary =
 NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as NSDictionary;
```

You need to do the json parsing like this:

```
var jsonError : NSError?

let jsonResult : AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &jsonError)

if let error = jsonError{
    println("error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
else if let jsonDict = jsonResult as? NSDictionary{
    println("json is dictionary \(jsonDict)")
}
else if let jsonArray = jsonResult as? NSArray{
    println("json is an array: \(jsonArray)")
}
```

That will work. Also remember json can come back as an array. Instead of passing nil for the options you can pass whatever you like, for example:

```
NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments
```

if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Now in beta-3

```
var error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?> = nil

var data: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( w, options:.AllowFragments, error: error ) as NSDictionary;
```

Comment: Thanks moby, '?' is unnecessary. So,
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil

Answer (score 0):

Check With below code:

```
var error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSErrorPointer?>=nil
var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response, error:nil)
var err: NSError?
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    println("Result\(jsonResult)")
```

Try using

```
 var error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSErrorPointer?>=nil
```