# JSON function doesn't parse for multiple JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a page that contains these json data :

```
{
   "time": "07:08:27 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
   "date": "03-05-2015"
},
{
   "time": "07:08:27 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
   "date": "03-05-2014"
},
```

and this is the code I use for parsing data :

```
 // 1
    let urlAsString = "http://192.168.1.35/ios"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    //2
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        // 3
        if var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
        if (err != nil) {
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        // 4
        let jsonDate: String! = jsonResult["date"] as NSString
        let jsonTime: String! = jsonResult["time"] as NSString

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    println(jsonDate)
        })
        }
    })
    // 5
    jsonQuery.resume()
```

The problem is that it only works if json data to be like this:

```
{
   "time": "07:08:27 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
   "date": "03-05-2015"
},
```

and for multiple json data it stop working.What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026305/how-do-i-parse-an-array-inside-parsed-json-in-swift

Comment: You may be missing an array wrapper around your json. Try `[{...},{...}]` instead of just `{...},{...}`.

Comment: @Alan I tried [{...},{...}] but it stop working even with single json data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider validating your JSON **[here](http://jsonlint.com/)**.

```
{
   "time": "07:08:27 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
   "date": "03-05-2015"
}
```

is a valid JSON.

[image]

while

```
{
    "time": "07:08:27 AM",
    "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
    "date": "03-05-2015"
},
{
    "time": "07:08:27 AM",
    "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
    "date": "03-05-2014"
}
```

is not.

[image]

### Edit:

JSON arrays are written inside square brackets. Your JSON should be:

```
[
    {
        "time": "07:08:27 AM",
        "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
        "date": "03-05-2015"
    },
    {
        "time": "07:08:27 AM",
        "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1425539307783,
        "date": "03-05-2014"
    }
]
```

You can refer **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)** and **[here](http://json.org/)** for more details.

Comment: thanks,But How should I write the correct one for that?

Comment: ,Thanks,I tried your answer but The code didn't return anything.

Comment: could you help me with that?I tried your answer for json data but nothing returns.What's the problem?

Comment: Wish I could, but I have **never** used Swift. You may want to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840203/parsing-json-array-in-swift). Good luck :)